# include vs. extend and Comparable module in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Looking for an explanation of an interesting Ruby observation. Consider mixing in the Comparable module as follows:

```
class Class0
end
class Class1
  include Comparable
end
class Class2
  extend Comparable
end
```

If we look for the methods which are in Class2 vs. Class0,

```
Class2.methods.each { |x| p x if not Class0.methods.include? x }
```

we get just :between?

But then, if we do this, to look for the difference between instances of Class1 and Class0,

```
a = Class0.new
b = Class1.new
b.methods.each { |x| p x if not a.methods.include? x }
```

we get

```
[:>, :>=, :<, :<=, :between?]
```

I would like to understand why the results are different. I would have expected the "extend" to push the same methods into the class that the "include" pushes into an instance. 
Are things like ":>" not methods in the same sense as ":between?"  ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include is for adding methods to an instance of a class and extend is for adding class methods:
http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/

Both :> and :between are methods. 
The difference is here:

If you see Class0 methods you have :>, :>=, :<, :<= defined as class methods. 
When Class2 extend Comparable it will get the between? method as class method.

In the second case you have Class0 and Class1 instances, so the a instance of Class0 doesn't have the :>, :>=, :<, :<=, :between? methods defined as instance methods. Once you include the comparable Module in Class1, it will get all this methods as instance methods from Module, so you will have all  [:>, :>=, :<, :<=, :between?] methods available in the instance b.

This is why you get those results.

I found another nice explanation of include VS extend here:
http://aaronlasseigne.com/2012/01/17/explaining-include-and-extend/

Comment: Thanks, @tbem, but that doesn't answer the question. The question is, why do they seem to do different things, one to the class, and the other to an instance? Why should they add different sets of methods?

Comment: thanks. I have not had a chance to read it carefully. Thanks for the answer and I will accept it as soon as I can.

Comment: thanks. Nice job. I wasn't doing the comparison exactly "straight-up". I need to study this a bit further still. But thanks so much (and for waiting until I finally had enough time to look at it)